# How to mock a union type in apollo client

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, apollo-client, react-testing-library

I want to test the apollo client with mock provider it is working correctly with simple query and mutation. But for register mutation I have response of the type

```
register(data: $data) {
      ... on Error {
        error {
          path
          message
        }
      }
      ... on RegisterSuccess {
        user {
          email
          _id
          username
        }
      }
    }
```

I have mocked this response with apollo client in the following way

```
const mocks = [
      {
        request: {
          query: RegisterMutation,
          variables: {
            data: {
              email: 'test',
              username: 'test',
              password: 'test',
            },
          },
        },
        result: {
          data: {
            register: {
              error: [
                {
                  path: 'email',
                  message: 'Email already in use',
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ];
```

But this is not working and giving error that,

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() Error: No more mocked responses for the query: mutation Register($data: RegisterInput!) {
      register(data: $data) {
        ... on Error {
          error {
            path
            message
          }
        }
        ... on RegisterSuccess {
          user {
            email
            _id
            username
          }
        }
      }
    }
    , variables: {"data":{"email":"","username":"","password":""}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a minor mistake from my side. I can not pass

```
{
   email: 'test',
   username: 'test',
   password: 'test',
}
```

this object as data in variables because component is expecting all three as empty string. So passing this

```
{
  email: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
}
```

had solved the issue for me.
refer this [github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6842) for more details and example